# How did this after hours massive NFLX short/long strategy make a profit?

Tags: equities, market-making, market, short-selling, earnings

I’ve seen thus market action 2 times now in the past few months.

The first was before ADBE earnings release,
and most recently was NFLX release.

The setup:

- Earnings release pending after hours
- Market closes
- Within the next minute or two after the market closes, but definitely before the earnings release, a massive short kicks in, dropping the price ~3 to 5% below the close
- ~10 seconds later the price reverses and the stock rises about 3 to 5% *above* the close.
- finally, within 10 seconds, the price drops again near the close.

Earnings weren’t released until 5 minutes later.

My thoughts:

- a fellow trader on StockTwits said that he has seen this type of action before in bear markets.
- it seems plausible that the massive short could have triggered a bunch of stop losses, allowing the algorithm to buy shares.  The subsequent massive long could have triggered a bunch of stops above the close, allowing the algorithm to sell those shares as the stops were triggered.

Questions:
Has anyone else seen this behavior?
Should it be legal to do this in an illiquid market just before earnings release?
Although plausible, it seems unlikely/counterintuitive that this would result in a net profit?

[image: NFLX after hours massive short/long candle]